# Content of initramfs

Tags: boot, initramfs

I've unpacked the cpio file initramfs-4.19.10-200.fc28.x86_64.img and only found this:

```
.
├── early_cpio
└── kernel
    └── x86
        └── microcode
            └── GenuineIntel.bin
```

Has this initramfs only one file? Years ago, I remember that such a files had a mini-filesystem. Where are those files now?

The OS is Fedora 28

Comment: Just unpacked the file in `Ubuntu` kernel `4.15.0-46` and got similar result. I suppose that `early_cpio` is not part of the initramfs because I don't have anything similar in my case (and you said "only one" file). If this is the case please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, maybe you can try to directly boot your OS without it, remember to pass `root` and `init` arguments to kernel. It seems like Fedora kernel doesn't run a init from initramfs now.

Answer (score 8):

initramfs images can contain multiple segments, and it’s common nowadays to have a short `cpio` archive containing early-boot files (such as microcode updates) before the main, compressed, `cpio` archive. In such circumstances you can use a tool such as [`lsinitramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/lsinitramfs) (on Debian and derivatives) or [`lsinitrd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsinitrd.1.html) (on Fedora, RHEL and derivatives) to view the full contents of the initramfs.

(`lsinitramfs` doesn’t support multi-segment files in general, but it does handle the special case described above. `lsinitrd` also supports the special case described above, I’m not sure whether it supports other multi-segment images.)